# How to do matrix multiplication with learnable weights in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, matrix-multiplication

I have a model like the one below. I want to add a matrix of learnable weights in the end, which is initialized to the variable **matrix** that I pass to the function create_model.

To get the intuitive idea of what I want to do, imagine the **matrix** is supposed to be the one I pass to the model, but I have the feeling that it can still be finetuned during training. Therefore, I want it to be initialized to the values I pass, and then refined during training.

The code below works, but as you see from the **model.summary()** output, the matrix multiplication contains no learnable weights, which makes me think that the weights of the matrix are not beeing finetuned.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 def create_model(num_columns, matrix):
    inp_layer = tfl.Input((num_columns,))
    dense = tfl.Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(inp_layer)
    dense = tfl.Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(dense)
    dense = tfl.Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(dense)

    va = tf.Variable(matrix, dtype = tf.float32)
    dense = K.dot(dense, va )
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inp_layer, outputs = dense)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=['binary_crossentropy'])
    model.summary()
    return model

matrix = np.random.randint(0,2,(128, 206)) # In reality, this is not random, but it has sensed values
num_columns = 750
model = create_model(num_columns,matrix)
```

[image: Model summary output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use a dense layer with no bias to do this multiplication. After the model is built I change the weight of interest with the matrix you provided

```
def create_model(num_columns, matrix):
    
    inp_layer = Input((num_columns,))
    x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(inp_layer)
    x = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(x)
    dense = Dense(206, use_bias=False)(x)
    
    model = Model(inputs = inp_layer, outputs = dense)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=['binary_crossentropy'])
    
    model.set_weights(model.get_weights()[:-1] + [matrix])
    model.summary()
    
    return model

matrix = np.random.randint(0,2,(128, 206)) # In reality, this is not random, but it has sensed values
num_columns = 750
model = create_model(num_columns,matrix)
```

check

```
(model.get_weights()[-1] == matrix).all() # True
```

In this way, the weights can be fine-tuned

Comment: Hi Marco,

The answer solves my problem. Thanks a lot :)
I've never stopped two minutes thinking the dense layer can be used that way, it's great :)

Still.. I'd like to understand why my approach doesn't work. When I initialize a tf.Variable, isn't it supposed to be part of the optimization graph?

Comment: Initialize a tf.Variable inside a functional/sequential model it's not a good idea... u can use it inside a custom layer that makes in your case a dot product. With sequential and functional model using a dense layer to make this is more elegant and controlled. Don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)